# What does "serve as any example" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does the sentence mean "If you consider Buffett as a role model to follow, you should use the discipline to buy things only when you really, really like them"?

**"If the Oracle of Omaha serves as any example, the discipline to buy things only when you really, really like them pays off."**

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/05/10/warren-buffetts-investment-strategy-can-help-you-build-wealth.html

Answer (score 1):

You basically got it.  "Serve*s* as an example" (note the 's') here means "is useful as an example".  So we have:

**"If the Oracle of Omaha serves as any example,"**

*IF Warren Buffet is a useful example*

**"the discipline to buy things only when you really, really like them"**

*having the discipline to wait for perfect investing opportunities*

**"pays off."**

*earns the investor a lot of money*

Answer (score 1):

The use of ***any*** rather than ***an*** in OP's cited example represents a relatively subtle choice of phrasing (it's a feature of [persuasive writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persuasive_writing)).

It's important to note that the clause starts with ***if***, which *in principle* already implies the writer and/or reader may in fact *not* think of Buffet ("the Oracle of Omaha") as an example.

Also note that ***any*** is effectively shorthand for ***any kind of example at all*** - so the ***if-*** statement should be considered "true" even if Buffet is in fact a really poor example (he's still [*an example "of sorts"*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of-sorts)).

But *in practice* we can be quite certain the writer *does* think Buffet is a [good] example, so in effect, this means the text acts something like a [rhetorical question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question). Superficially, the words seem to imply there's room for different opinions on whether Buffet is a good role model to follow, but the writer takes it for granted all his readers will admire Buffet and see him as a source of sound advice.

---

Consider over 7000 written instances of [*if I'm **any** judge*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22if%20I%27m%20any%20judge%22) in Google Books (for comparison, note that there are only 6 instances of [*if I'm **a** judge*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22if%20I%27m%20any%20judge%22#tbm=bks&q=%22if%20I'm%20a%20judge%22)). In such contexts, the speaker isn't normally admitting there's some possibility that he might *not* be a good judge of whatever he's opining on - he's implying that *no matter how bad a judge he might be*, his opinion is reliable, and should be agreed with.

---

TL;DR: The writer is claiming that if you follow the dictum *have the self-discipline to only buy things if **really** like them,* this will definitely "pay off" (be profitable). He strongly implies this is *obviously* true because that's what Warren Buffet always says, and he's made a *lot* of money over the years (thus *anybody* could reasonably look to him as a good example to follow).

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: Yeah. Noting that the text is primarily aimed at potential investors, I reckon the implicit rhetorical question in the "subtext" is something along the lines *You do want to be successful like Warren Buffet, **don't you**?* (the writer isn't interested in any readers who might be unsure about their answer there).